# Disable critical battery event

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery

I have a battery that is a bit messed up and probably needs to be replaced.  In the meantime, I would to use it without it automatically going into sleep mode.  Sometimes this happens after about 20 minutes, without any warnings.  It doesn't seem to matter at what level I put the alarms.  After about 5 minutes of being plugged in again, the battery seems fully charged.

This is with Windows 7.  When I using XP, I could turn off the battery critical event handler all together, and just use the laptop until the power literally ran out. Yes, it's like a crash and requires a reboot, but if you are expecting it, not the bad at all actually, especially to maximize the usuge of your PC when on battery.

Is there a way to do this on Windows 7 or 8?

P.S.  My laptop also has an overheating problem, and the issues may be related, however, I don't know which came first.  I may make another post on the overheating.  But basics of preventing overheating have been applied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, it's not a good idea to discharge you battery below a certain threshold if you at least a bit care about its life. Too late for you, but you can still [read why](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries). That's probably also the reason why the wise ones at Microsoft decided to not allow you to set the critical level below 3% and also prevent you from ignoring the critical event.

Still, what's not available from the dropdowns seems to be possible via command line tool `POWERCFG`. If you run the following command from an elevated command console (`CMD` Run as Administrator) you'll get exactly what you are asking for:

```
POWERCFG /SETDCVALUEINDEX SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_BATTERY BATACTIONCRIT 0
```

This command will set the critical battery event handler to "Do Nothing" when running on battery in your currently selected power scheme (see `POWERCFG /L` for all schemes), thus your system will die only when the battery protection circuit cuts the power off.

[image: Do Nothing for Critical battery action]

You can also run `POWERCFG /?` to get all its options or `POWERCFG /QUERY` to see all your power settings and their possible values.

Comment: I actually haven't tried this yet, I might save it for a special time.  But it seems like this is what I want.  Also, interestingly enough, my PC was caught in a weird shut down state at one point in time, and lasted more than an hour on the batter.

Comment: As observed by @irthinker, when your battery is so messed up that it even loses charge when AC is plugged in, you'll also want to set the `Plugged in` option to `Do nothing` otherwise you'll also taste the system's wrath. This, however is still possible to do from the usual graphical dialog (At least on Windows 10, where I just looked), so those allergic to command line can cut the exposure to the abovementioned bare minimum. Those who dare can also use `POWERCFG /SETACVALUEINDEX SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_BATTERY BATACTIONCRIT 0`

Answer (score -1):

I would have commented on tlwhitec's great answer, but I cannot since I am new. I have a little bit to add to that.

When you use `powercfg -setdcvalueindex SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_BATTERY BATACTIONCRIT 0` you are telling it to do nothing when your computer is not plugged in.

I would recommend also doing this for when the computer is plugged in, because, by default it will want to hibernate when it sees that critical battery level.

Not surprisingly, you are just changing 'dc' to 'ac' for that:

```
powercfg -setacvalueindex SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_BATTERY BATACTIONCRIT 0
```

I also want to point out that these commands will only change it for the current power scheme, (hence `SCHEME_CURRENT`). Something to keep in mind if you decide you might want to change your "power plan" later.

Comment: Hi @itrhinker, have you in fact observed the system to trigger on battery level events when on AC? I would consider that pretty much a bug on the Windows side. I have never observed such behavior - Once I plug the AC in, the battery actions are ignored. 
I suppose the possibility to set the battery values for AC are just to maintain settings symmetry, but the `SUB_BATTERY` values really don't matter. This of course shouldn't apply to other subgroups like `LIDACTION` or `SUB_VIDEO`.

Comment: Absolutely. I had a laptop battery in an ultralaptop that was failing to charge, so it slowly lost it's charge over time. It was not worth the cost to get a new battery. However, when it reached a very low level it started automatically sleeping/shutting off (can't remember now) and this was the only way to prevent it from happening. Once I made this change (and no others), I had no issues and could leave the laptop on for days (if plugged in of course). A very clean, simple data point.

Comment: Good to know! Still it's a little offtopic in regards to the original question which seeks a way how to do something that's not possible via the usual GUI. Thus I've added your recommendation as a comment under my post. I hope you find it legit, too ;)

Comment: Sounds good, getting the info out there is the whole point. Thanks! :-)